# COUNTIFS Formula Breaks When VBA script is Ran

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA script that cleans up the data from a very long report.
I copy the data into the excel file which contains the VBA script and then run the VBA script.

On another sheet on the same excel file, I have a formula of COUNTIFS.
However, whenever I run the VBA script, the COUNTIFS formula breaks on the ranges portion of the formula.

`=COUNTIFS('Open IM'!#REF!,"11-20 Days ",'Open IM'!#REF!,"Arizona")`

Is there a way to "solidify" the ranges so that it does not break when the VBA is ran on a new set of data?

This is how thw working formula looks like:

`=COUNTIFS('Open IM'!$G:$G,"11-20 Days ",'Open IM'!$D:$D,"Arizona")`

I have tried the below as well but no dice:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

and

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Looks like your script (that is not shared) deletes a range that your formula refers to. Instead of deleting you may consider clearcontents.

Comment: You could place your data within a table (`Ctrl+T` to create a table).  Your formula is then:  `=COUNTIF(Table1[MyData],"11-20 Days ")` so it's not looking at the whole column (not sure if COUNTIF slows down with a whole column reference?).  Highlight the table data and select Delete > Table Rows which won't break the formula.